# Retrieving excel file from internal storage Apache POI

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi, adt

I'm trying to open a file in Apache POI, the file is located in internal storage and I'm trying to access it using getFilesDir() as follows:

```
File file = new File(fname);
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/"+fname);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

It's not working! I don't know what is wrong. I've tried context.getFilesDir() as well and to no avail. I'm a relative newbie so obviously I'm doing something wrong. Rest of the code is under as well and is open to critique!

```
try {
  File file = new File(fname);
  OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/"+fname);
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);

  // Get the first sheet from workbook 
  XSSFSheet mySheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

  while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
    HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
    Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();

    while(cellIter.hasNext()){
      HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
      String TAG = "ExelLog";
      Log.d(TAG , "Cell Value: " +  myCell.toString());
      System.out.println("Cell Value: " +  myCell.toString());
      Toast.makeText(context, "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   }
 } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("error1");
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: How is it not working? Is it giving an error?  Without more details about the failure, we can't help...

Comment: Well the problem is in the initial block. It does not give out an error but there are a lot of warning in LogCat. That's why I initially had couts (system.out.printlns) to trace the error. If I system.out before the line File file = new File(fname); after try, it works, but it does not system.out after  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);. Hope you can help thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is pointing to the right place? `context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/"+fname`

Comment: akokskis... the error is in this line
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/"+fname);

no I am pretty sure it's not the right path now. Problem is I don't know what the correct path is. And that was my attempt at getting to the file (I did a lot of reading and this is what I came up with)

Comment: It also gives out an error which says "error opening trace file: no such file or directory (2)", the last time this error showed up I just increased the emulator's SD card memory and that fixed it. But now I think it's related to that path.

Comment: "no such file or directory" - well, there's your problem right there. Figure out the correct path and you should be all set

Comment: @akokskis okay so I found the path using `File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fname);` and then used `OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);`, the error has gone away but it still isn't working///